# DocumentBuilder parsing breaks string when hits '&amp;'

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, escaping

i have this xml:
`<user>

    <name>H &amp; M</name>`

and i parse it using this code:

```
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = null;
            Document document = null;
```

try {
            documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
            .newDocumentBuilder();
            document = documentBuilder.parse(is);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return result;
        }

        NodeList nl = document.getElementsByTagName(XML_RESPONSE_ROOT);
        if (nl.getLength() > 0) {
            resp_code = nl.item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem(
                    XML_RESPONSE_STATUS).getNodeValue();

            if (resp_code.equals(RESP_CODE_OK_SINGLE)) {
                nl = document
                .getElementsByTagName(XML_RESPONSE_TAG_CONTACT);
                NodeList values = nl.item(i).getChildNodes();

etc..

when i get the node value by: node.getNodeValue();

i get only what's before the ampersand, even though the ampersand is escaped

i want to get the whole string: "H & M"

thanks

Comment: DOM allows an element node to break its textual content into multiple adjacent text nodes. However, the JDK implies that entity reference nodes will not be used for built-in entities, so I don't know why this is happening. (Best answer, though, is: don't use the DOM. There are much better tree models around, such as JDOM and XOM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how your XML document was constructed. In particular, it can have multiple adjucent Text nodes in "H & M" while your code expects it to be just one. Try to use nodeVariable.normalize() before getting its value.

According to DOM parser API: "normalize() - Puts all Text nodes in the full depth of the sub-tree underneath this Node, including attribute nodes, into a "normal" form where only structure (e.g., elements, comments, processing instructions, CDATA sections, and entity references) separates Text nodes, i.e., there are neither adjacent Text nodes nor empty Text nodes..."

Answer (score 0):

Find the "name" Element and call `getTextContent()`.

Comment: @pat - i don't think you called it on the right node then.  on the _Element_ node, it will return all concatenated children.  if you call it on the child itself, it will only return the partial text.