# Don't want to change &apos; entity to ' in XML file

Tags: java, xml

I am automating changing of some XML files through documentation builder factory 
but in the one of the attribute entity reference `&apos;` getting change to `'` . I don't want that change to happen.

```
docBuilderFactory.setValidating(false);
docBuilderFactory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
```

but nothing seems to work

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181704/documentbuilder-parsing-breaks-string-when-hits-amp) help?

Comment: i tried doing normalise ....and attr.getNamedItem(somenode).getTextContent() but still the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more of a hack, but you can escape it before processing:

```
myXmlString = myXmlString.replaceAll("&apos;", "&amp;apos;").
```

Then the processor will expand `&amp;apos;` to `&apos;`.

Comment: i have thought of this ....but the problem is i m using attr.getNamedItem(someNode).getNodeValue() this gives me changed ' so not able to recognize simple ' or &apos;

Answer (score 0):

The real issue is that `&apos;` is merely a way to escape the apostrophe. This is like reading a string in JavaScript: `'\''`, once the data is interpreted as string the escaped characters (entities in XML) are expanded by the parser. That is, the parsing step from raw characters to  =  fundamentally includes this interpretation and there is no good way around it.

Presumably the real problem is output of valid XML after transformation, where the issue lies in the fact that your original input string is parsed and the entity expanded to apostrophe. Fortunately this is an easy fix: if you know certain attributes might have apostrophes, you can code your output step to include a search & replace pass, where `'` is converted into `&apos;`.

(This is similar to writing out raw JavaScript strings in JavaScript and having to convert apostrophes back to `\'`)

Comment: the problem is i am using DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder(); Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("book.xml")); and then i take the stringContent of any node or attribute i am not getting the string content i am getting the parsed content ...if anyhow i get the string content, i can make use of that