# I want to parse JSON in Java for Android but neither Gson nor Jackson works correctly

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I have a C# web service which returns soap with a JSON string which looks like

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <getAndroidVersionResponse xmlns="http://development.com/">
            <getAndroidVersionResult>{"Valid":false,"Url":"http://localhost/test","Av":[{"Valid":true,"Url":"Som!@#$%^&amp;*()_+{}:&lt;>?\"''\\\"\\\"eURL","Av":null},{"Valid":false,"Url":"SomeURLSeond","Av":null}]}</getAndroidVersionResult>
        </getAndroidVersionResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The object is Serialized using `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);`

For normal non-weird strings Gson and Jackson work just fine, but when I do a combination of weird characters then both of them cannot deserialize it.

When I validate the string online with [Json Parser Online](http://json.parser.online.fr/) and [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), there is no problem with it.

```
{"Valid":false,"Url":"http://localhost/test","Av":[{"Valid":true,"Url":"Som!@#$%^&amp;*()_+{}:&lt;>?\"''\\\"\\\"eURL","Av":null},{"Valid":false,"Url":"SomeURLSeond","Av":null}]}
```

---

***Json Parser Online***

[image: Valid JSON]

---

***JSONLint***

[image: Valid JSON]

---

The code I am using for them:

```
/*GSON*/
com.google.gson.Gson gson = new com.google.gson.Gson();
AndroidVersion v = gson.fromJson(subList.item(0).getNodeValue(), AndroidVersion.class);

/*Jackson*/
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.PASCAL_CASE_TO_CAMEL_CASE);
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
AndroidVersion v = mapper.readValue(subList.item(0).getNodeValue(), AndroidVersion.class);
```

Any other approach I can take with this? I have come across [Boon-JSON](https://github.com/boonproject/boon/wiki/Boon-JSON-in-five-minutes) but it does not look promising.

I thought by now `Newtonsoft` would have Redone **Newtonsoft.JSON** for Java because that library is just excellent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your models like for example:

```
public class AndroidVersion {
    public boolean Valid;
    public String Url;
    public List <AndroidVersion> Av;
}
```

And then use Gson like below:

```
String jsonString = "Your json string here";
AndroidVersion v = gson.fromJson(jsonString, AndroidVersion.class);
```

Comment: Thank you KushtrimP, that is what I currently have but the problem is not in the mapping, it's in the data parsing, The URL string for example breaks with extra double quotes, If it is only a normal url string, it works perfectly fine. I will have to cater for all weird combination of characters

Comment: It has something to do with the special characters. Try this String, see if it works :           
        String jsonString = "{\"Valid\":false,\"Url\":\"http://localhost/test\",\"Av\":[{\"Valid\":true,\"Url\":\"Som!@#$%^&amp;*()_+{}:&lt;>?\\\"''\\\"\\\"eURL\",\"Av\":null},{\"Valid\":false,\"Url\":\"SomeURLSeond\",\"Av\":null}]}";

Comment: I have thought about that as well, But in the xml it looks like there is no escapes for the double quotes, but when it is in the Java String variable, there is in fact escapes, I have now removed character for character to see which one's the culprit, these three characters doesn't work in the URL string `&<>`, it looks like it is html encoded `&amp;`, `&lt;`. It looks like this is a Java problem and not a Gson or Jackson problem. Java doesn't like html encoded characters?

Comment: Try using StringEscapeUtils from apache commons library:  
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: Okay I found the problem, yes you are correct! When I receive the soap response, I use `DocumentBuilderFactory`, `DocumentBuilder`, `StringReader`, `InputSource`, `Document` and `Element`. It breaks when doing `DocumentBuilder.parse(incomingString);` I will escape the incoming string and see the magic happen

Comment: `StringEscapeUtils` did not help, I have added `DocumentBuilder.normalizeDocument();` after `DocumentBuilder.parse(incomingString);` and it works perfectly. This post helped http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181704/documentbuilder-parsing-breaks-string-when-hits-amp Thanks for your help, wouldn't have come so far...